# When to remove error color from field? On change or on focus?

Tags: forms, input-fields, ux-field, errors

I have a form. When the user puts in wrong information or an error shows up, the field color changes. Now, I'm confused as to when I should change the color back; should it be when the user focuses onto the field (onfocus), or when he starts typing again (onchange)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would **suggest changing it once the user has entered a valid input**. This would ensure that the user is aware that the input so far is not valid and once a valid input is entered, the visual change informs the user about the successful entry.

You should hence look at live inline validation to ensure users get feedback dynamically. To quote this [article from smashing magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/27/form-field-validation-errors-only-approach/)

> [image]
>
> Here, each form field is validated separately as the user types. The
>   error handling is most often instant, with the user being told that
>   their data doesn’t match the expected format (although the user can
>   scroll past and try to submit the form anyway). Luke Wroblewski has
>   done some excellent usability research on the inline validation
>   techniques that work best.